# Integration and periodic divergent series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, divergent-series, periodic-functions

Consider the divergent infinite series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty 5^n \cos(nt) $$

where $t \in \mathbb{R}$.  I don't believe it has a closed form.  However, if I take the integral with respect to $t$:

$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty 5^n \cos(nt) \, dt = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 5^n \int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(nt) \, dt$$
$$ = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 5^n \cdot 0 = 0$$

So even though the series is divergent it still has a finite integral.  This seems to be a consequence of the fact that it's periodic over the integration domain: the infinities sort of cancel each other out.

This can extend also to the product of series:
$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty 5^n \cos(nt) \right) \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {7^n} \cos(nt) \right) \,dt$$
$$ = \pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac 5 7 \right)^n = \frac 5 2 \pi$$

I'm trying to understand the underlying properties at work here.  Specifically, is there a way to come up with a "closed form" for a periodic infinite divergent series which behaves the same under integration (for instance, something I could use with integration by parts) without actually being the limit of the partial sums of $f(t)$?  That is, something like a proxy function with the infinities sort of preemptively normalized out?

Comment: The summation and integration are not exchangeable in $$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n \cos(nt) \, dt $$ unless $|a|<1$.

Comment: @Quanto that's true but the integral of any finite subseries will be 0.  It's playing a bit fast and loose with the infinities to give the integral of the infinite sum a value, but afterall that's kind of the heart of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking about *asymptotics*$^\dagger$. Specifically assigning a meaning to divergent series. The strategy is to first construct something that *does* converge out of your series. Using [Borel summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation), we write

$$ \phi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Where the $c_n$ are given by your series

$$ c_n =5^n \cos(nt)$$

Now let

$$ B(x)=\int_0^\infty  dz \ \phi(xz)\exp(-z)$$

We will define your (divergent) sum as $B(1)$, if that exists. It's not obvious, but the above things are defined so that $B(1)=\sum_n c_n$, which follows after a few manipulations. In any case, with the assistance of Mathematica, I find

$$\phi(x)=\cos(5x\sin(t)) \left( \cosh(5x\cos(t))+\sinh(5x\cos(t))\right)$$

$$B(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left( 1+\frac{1}{1-5xe^{it}}+\frac{5x}{-5x+e^{it}} \right)$$

$$ B(1) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{6}{-13+5\cos(t)}$$

This is nice, but the manipulations are obscure and the integrals annoying. Let us apply [Euler summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation) to get the same answer with much less fuss$^\ddagger$. Let

$$ I(x)=\sum_n c_n x^n $$

With the $c_n$ given by your series.  This is more intuitive than Borel summation because it is obvious that when $x=1$, we have $\sum_n c_n$, which is your original sum. We will define $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}I(x)$ as that sum, if the limit exists. Substituting your $c_n$

$$ I(x)=\sum_n (5x)^n \cos(nt)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_n (5x)^n \left(e^{int}+e^{-int} \right)$$

$$ I(x)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( 5xe^{it} \right)^n +\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( 5xe^{-it} \right)^n$$

We now have two geometric series, and importantly, they *converge* for $|x|<1/5$.

$$ I(x)=\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-5xe^{it}}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-5xe^{-it}}$$

Having performed the sum, we take the limit $x \rightarrow 1$ to find

$$ I(1)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{6}{-13+5\cos(t)}$$

Which we may define as the value of your sum. As promised, $I(1)=B(1)$. Why does this (sometimes) work? Because for small enough $x$, perhaps $I(x)$ converges, even though the original sum didn't. Similar logic applies to Borel summation, with that terrific $1/n!$ damping of terms.

$\dagger$ Too large a topic to explain here. I'll just refer you to Carl Bender's excellent book: *Advanced mathematical methods*.

$\ddagger$ There are other types of summation, too. For a given series, some may work while others fail.

EDIT: Using a method inspired by the other answer:

For real $t$, the sum must diverge because $|\cos|\leq1$ but $5^n$ grows exponentially, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}c_n \neq0$. However, if we allow $t \in \mathbb{C}$, and writing $\cos$ in exponential form, the sums converge for $t$ with sufficiently large imaginary part. After performing the sum we can define the answer to be $\lim_{\Im(t)\rightarrow 0}$, which turns out to be exactly $B(1)$.

Comment: Thanks!  This is a good introduction to a whole subject I didn't know existed!  Can you double check the value of $B(1)$ you got?  I think the $\frac{1}{2}$ factor should be positive maybe?  So that the integral is 0 (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+6+%2F+%28-13+%2B+5+cos%28t%29%29+%2B+1%2F2+dt+from+0+to+2pi)

Comment: My pleasure! Yes, that is my mistake: I have corrected the offending minus sign in $B(1)$

Comment: Can you expand a bit on the math between the integral expression for $B(x)$ to actually evaluating $B(1)$?  I got as far as $\phi(x) = \frac 1 2 \exp(5 x \exp(it)) + \frac 1 2 \exp(5 x \exp(-it))$, but plugging that in to the integral gives a divergent integral, so there must be some additional trick I'm missing.

Comment: Don't forget the factor $\exp(-z)$ in the integral! I asked Mathematica to do the integral for $B(x)$, and it took her quite some time to return the answer, so presumably it's a tricky one!

Comment: Yeah I have the $\exp(-z)$ term in there.  Do you have the closed form expression for $B(x)$ handy?  That might give me enough of a hint to figure it out.

Comment: Sure, I've added it to my post. Good luck!

Comment: Okay, so I've confirmed the value of $\phi(x)$ just fine but I can't for the life of me get a finite value for the integral.  The hyperbolic trig terms grow faster than the $\exp(-z)$ terms.  Do you think you can give more detail on how the integral is happening?  Mathematica has lied to me before so I don't want to blindly trust it.

Comment: @JayLemmon This is a gentle reminder to 'accept' an answer if your question has been resolved. As for your integral, I'd suggest starting another question for it.

Comment: I genuinely appreciate the help here but if I don't feel comfortable accepting this as the answer if I can't independently verify the integral in some way.  All the integration techniques I threw at it seemed to show it was divergent.

Comment: That was my mistake. I should have *first* used Euler summation, instead of Borel, so that you didn't get immediately dragged into obscure integrals. I had *intended* that if you got stuck on the integral, you could get the (correct) answer using Euler summation, but looking at my answer, I see that was not obvious. I've edited my post with a demonstration of using Euler summation to get the answer; no integrals required!

Answer (score 0):

If we denote the series:
$$S_N(t)=\sum_{n=1}^N5^n\cos(nt)$$
$$s_N(t)=\sum_{n=1}^N5^n\sin(nt)$$
then we can see that:
$$S_N(t)+is_N(t)=\sum_{n=1}^N5^ne^{int}=\sum_{n=1}^N\left(5e^{it}\right)^n$$
Now we have a geometric series so we can say:
$$A_N=S_N(t)+is_N(t)=\frac{\left(5e^{it}\right)^{N+1}-1}{5e^{it}}$$
now we can try and split this up into real and imaginary parts:
$$A_N=e^{-it}\frac{(5e^{it})^{N+1}-1}{5}=(5e^{it})^N-\frac{e^{-it}}{5}$$
$$A_N=5^N\left[\cos(Nt)+i\sin(Nt)\right]-\frac15\left[\cos(t)-i\sin(t)\right]$$
and so we can deduce:
$$S_N(t)=5^N\cos(Nt)-5^{-1}\cos(t)$$
so for certain values of $t$ it is possible that $S_{N\to\infty}(t)$ converges

Comment: The geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (5 e^{it})^n$ is divergent.  The formula you're thinking about, where a geometric series converges to $\frac 1 {1 - r}$, requires that the ratio of successive terms ($r$) be less than one.  But here it's $5$ and the limit of partial sums doesn't exist.